# Read validation attribute from Object

Tags: c#, validation, reflection

I have an object which has properties decorated with Validation attributes. My validation is working correctly, however I need an additional method which performs string manipulation based on those attributes.

Consider the following object:

```
public class Pupil
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public Pupil()
    {

    }

    [NotNullValidator]
    [StringLengthValidator(0, 54, MessageTemplate = "Invalid value '{0}' for {1}, Max length: {5}")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [NotNullValidator]
    [StringLengthValidator(0, 2, MessageTemplate = "Invalid value '{0}' for {1}, Max length: {5}")]
    public string Gender{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to manipulate the "Name" based on the StringLengthValidator attribute and its arguments. For example:

```
///Takes a Pupil object in
public static void DoManipulation(object value)
    {
        foreach(var property in value.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if(property.Name == "Name")
            {
                var att = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringLengthValidator), false);
                var length = ((StringLengthValidator)att[0]).UpperBound;

            }               
        }
    }
```

The value of "length" is coming up as null, rather than 54. How do I get the value out?
Hopefully this makes sense, thanks.

A

Comment: Are you sure length is null?  It is an integer property, so I strongly doubt it.  Are you sure it is getting to the point where it sets length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, are you getting the same `StringLengthValidator` attribute that you think you are? (is this your custom class or the one from Enterprise Lib?

In my case, I created a custom class `StringLengthValidator`

[image]

Comment: I am using the one from the Enterprise Library.

Comment: I have no idea why this isn't working, but if I use a Custom attribute then it works fine. A custom attribute works out better for me in this instance, so that's for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind all this is that the value 54 can be changed, right? Otherwise you could just hard code 54.

Take a look on how to contol validation in the web.config with the  tag so you can  add the 54 to the web.config and read it from your application

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/256355/Microsoft-Enterprise-Library-5-0-Introduction-to-V) is an example, look for the first approach, `Rule sets in Configuration`

Comment: @Justin the value of "att" is null and therefore "length" returns an indexOutOfBounds exception.
Diego, the object above only has 2 properties but my actual object has 6 complex types and each of these have further complex properties, so I would like to do it dynamically rather than write a large configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

As I was looking for it today with my co-worker and we did not find a proper solution to our problem, here is the answer, for the next one who is in trouble.

The attribute name is `StringLengthValidator`, but if you check at the class name it is `StringLengthValidatorAttribute`, so in order to get the proper attribute, you need to call the function `GetCustomAttributes` this way :

```
property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringLengthValidatorAttribute), false)
```

This will fetch correctly the attribute and then you will be able to get the value of `UpperBound`